# Why the list doesn't re-render after updating the store?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I started learning mobx and got stuck. Why when I change `listItems`, List doesn't re-render?

I have store:

```
export const listStore = () => {
    return makeObservable(
        {
            listItems: [],
            addItem(text) {
                this.listItems.push(text);
            }
        },
        {
            listItems: observable,
            addItem: action.bound
        }
    );
};
```

Component that adds text from input to store:

```
const store = listStore();

export const ListForm = observer(() => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => store.addItem(value)}>Add note</button>
        </>
    );
});
```

And I have a list component:

```
const store = listStore();

export const List = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                <Observer>
                    {() => store.listItems.map(item => {
                        return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
                    }
                </Observer>
            </ul>
            <ListForm />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Looks like the list doesn't watch the store changing

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-firefly-lkh3e?file=/src/ListForm.jsx

Comment: Your second snippet in incorrect, you have store code there instead of component. Also, to make it easier, just make a reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/ please

Comment: Oh, thank you, man. codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-firefly-lkh3e?file=/src/ListForm.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create 2 different instances of the store, they don't share data between. Just create one singleton instance, like that:

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action } from 'mobx';

const createListStore = () => {
  return makeObservable(
    {
      listItems: [],
      addItem(text) {
        this.listItems.push(text);
      }
    },
    {
      listItems: observable,
      addItem: action.bound
    }
  );
};

export const store = createListStore();
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70153516-cjz56?file=/src/ListForm.jsx)